# "this" is undefined

Tags: flash, actionscript, this, tween

I am a java/php developer helping someone with actionscript.  I don't understand why "this" is undefined in the below code.  this is only a snippet of the code, but hopefully it's gives an idea of where i'm trying to reference "this".  I'm trying to find out which movie the tween is moving so that i can load the next movie.  Tweens are used to move the movies in and out of the screen.

```
var tween_move_1:Tween = new Tween(movie_0, "_x", Strong.easeOut, 1600, 150, 0.5, true);

tween_move_1.onMotionFinished = function() {
    stop();
    setTimeout(function () {
        trace(this);//when trace runs it shows undefined
        var tween_move_2:Tween = new Tween(movie_0, "_x", Strong.easeOut, 150, 1600, 0.5, true);
        tween_move_2.onMotionFinished = function() {
        var tween_move_1:Tween = new Tween(movie_1, "_x", Strong.easeOut, 1600, 150, 0.5, true);
        };
    }
    ,2000);//end of setTimeout
};//end of tween.onMotionFinished
```

**UPDATE!  Here is the working code after applying tips from the responses/answers:**

```
var tween_move_in:Tween = new Tween(movie_0, "_x", Strong.easeOut, 1600, 150, 0.5, true);   
tween_move_in.onMotionFinished = function() {
    stop();
    var tweeny = this;//create reference to this so it can be used in setTimeout()
    setTimeout(function () {
         var movie = tweeny.obj;//use ref to get the movie affected by the tween
         var movieName:String = movie._name;
         var splitArray = movieName.split("_");
         var index = parseInt(splitArray[1]);
         var tween_move_out:Tween = new Tween(_root["movie_"+index], "_x", Strong.easeOut, 150, 1600, 0.5, true);
         tween_move_out.onMotionFinished = function() {
              var tween_move_in2:Tween = new Tween(_root["movie_"+(index+1)], "_x", Strong.easeOut, 1600, 150, 0.5, true);
         };
    }
    ,2000);//end of setTimeout
};//end of tween.onMotionFinished
```

Comment: Also the reference page for the tween class helped.
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/transitions/Tween.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trying to trace out `tween_move_1`, you can refer to it directly inside the `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Thx this along with the tip from Daniel below pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here's what's up...

when you use `new function () {this}` as in `SetTimeout(function () {`etc.

This creates an empty (undefined) object, this object is not the same as the object that is calling the function

While I can't tell you what you should do, as I don't know what you're trying to do, I hope this helps you figure it out.

you could however either reference the function (var foo:Function ...) and pass a variable foo($var:Type)

Answer (score 0):

If the particular `this` that you want to pass in is the one that's available at the scope where you defined `tween_move_1`, then make another local variable, fill it with `this`, and use that new variable instead.

```
var tween_move_1:Tween ...
var foo:* = this;
...
    setTimeout(function () {
        trace(foo);
```